# Creating a tree from a list in Clojure

Tags: list, clojure, tree

Hello I am new to Clojure,

I am trying to solve the following problem[1](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/5/544.html)

My first step into solving this problem is to write a function that receives a list (in my case, of place names) and turns that into a tree.

```
(list 'Karlsruhe 'Stuttgart '100 'Stuttgart 'Ulm '80 'Ulm 'Muenchen '120)
```

I would like the tree to look like this:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSmqL.png)

The reason I want the tree to look like that is, I plan to write a function that receives a goal and destination, searches the newly created tree for the goal keeping a note of all the right hand nodes, then at the end, does a check to see which is the smallest and returns that.

I would just like some help/guidance Thanks.

M.

Comment: This is not a platform to solve your homework for you. Please provide any code example...

Comment: also, it's not a clojure question anyway. It's algorithm question. Maybe you can provide your thoughts, and attempts. The task is easy to fulfill, but you should try first.

Comment: Is this an easy task? I'm having trouble understanding what exactly the asker is trying to do. OP, could you edit your question with more details on the problem you're trying to solve and the code you've written so far to try to solve it?

Comment: well, as far as i understand, he wants to get something like this: `{:value Karlsruhe, :left {:value Stuttgart, :left {:value Ulm, :left nil, :right [120]}, :right [80]}, :right [100]}` , or well maybe a different structure of the same form. So he needs just one small recursive fn for that. But yeah, the question is not well formed at all.

Comment: @leetwinski , I am sorry for the poor formation of my question, I have updated it now. I hope that helps you some more. I am certainly not assuming this platform is for solving my homework, I just wanted some guidance , perhaps that was not clear due to my poor question, its my first time, sorry. M.

Comment: is it true that from every city you can go to just one next city?

Comment: @leetwinski Yes, i believe so.

Comment: then you don't really need any tree for that. Ok i'll make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the thing you are trying to do could be perfectly done without constructing the tree. You have triplets here in your list with source, destination and some number. So i would make a map of `source` to `[destination number]` here, for better lookup, and then recursively traverse it:

```
(def items (list 'Karlsruhe 'Stuttgart '100 
                 'Stuttgart 'Ulm '80 
                 'Ulm 'Muenchen '120))

(def items-lookup-map (into {} 
                        (map (juxt first rest) 
                             (partition 3 items)))
```

now your lookup map looks like this:

```
{Karlsruhe (Stuttgart 100), 
 Stuttgart (Ulm 80), 
 Ulm (Muenchen 120)}
```

so now you can easily write a function that finds a path from source to destination:

```
(defn find-path [source dest lookup-map]
  (let [[prev [dest & _]] (split-with
                           #(and (not (nil? %)) (not= % dest))
                           (iterate #(first (lookup-map %))
                                    source))]
    (when dest (concat prev [dest]))))
```

let's test:

```
user> (find-path 'Karlsruhe 'Ulm items-lookup-map)
(Karlsruhe Stuttgart Ulm)
user> (find-path 'Karlsruhe 'Prague items-lookup-map)
nil
user> (find-path 'Moscau 'Ulm items-lookup-map)
nil
```

now you can do whatever you want with it, for example find a minimum number in path:

```
(defn min-distance [src dest lookup-map]
  (when-let [path (seq (find-path src dest lookup-map))]
    (apply min (map #(second (lookup-map %)) (butlast path)))))

user> (min-distance 'Karlsruhe 'Muenchen items-lookup-map)
80
```

Comment: Thank you so much , its probably going to take me some time to go through it and make sure i understand what is going on. 

in your example of finding a minimum number in a path , how would that translate into a function, so it can be called with any place like:

 (findMin 'Karlsruhe 'Ulm)

Comment: just wrap it in `defn`

Comment: `(defn find-path[source dest lookup-map]
(when-let [path (seq (find-path source dest lookup-map))]
  (apply min (map #(second (items-lookup-map %)) (butlast path)))))`

fails.

Comment: no, you should better leave `find-path` function, as it is universal. better add new one, that will use `find-path`

Comment: sorry, i meant 

`(defn find-min[source dest lookup-map]
(when-let [path (seq (find-path source dest lookup-map))]
  (apply min (map #(second (items-lookup-map %)) (butlast path)))))`